# Animation completion block run prior to finish?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm display a `UIViewController` modally using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` in order to perform an animation.

```
[self presentViewController:messageVC animated:NO completion:^{
[messageVC displayMessageAutoReversed:YES withBlock:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        [messageVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
}];
```

inside `messageVC`, this method is called:

```
-(void)displayMessageAutoReversed:(BOOL)autoReversed withBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))handler {
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.4;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.5 initialSpringVelocity:2.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

        self.visualEffectView.effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:self.blurEffectStyle];
        self.messageLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
        self.imageView.alpha = 1.0f;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished)
        {
            if (autoReversed)
            {
                [self hideMessageWithBlock:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (handler) { handler(finished); }
                }];
            } else
            {
                if (handler) { handler(finished); }
            }
        }
    }];
}

-(void)hideMessageWithBlock:(void (^)(BOOL finished))handler {
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.4;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:animationDuration + 1.5 usingSpringWithDamping:1.5 initialSpringVelocity:2.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil;
        self.messageLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (handler) { handler(finished); }
    }];
}
```

but the animation block inside `hideMessageWithBlock` is called instantly, rather than after the 1.9 second delay - which sets the effect to nil before it suddenly bounces back to blurry. **Why is this?** It sort of flickers to `nil` and then jumps back to being blurry, before it fades out correct after another second.

**Edit:**

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t reverseTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
 dispatch_after(reverseTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    /* put whole animation block here? */
});
```

Comment: I am not sure `visualEffectView` animation will work with spring animation.

Comment: @sulthan hmm, strange. Has to be well partially working considering it's animating correctly with the exception of the flicker

Comment: @Paulw11 seems plausible, but how come you can fade / animate the blur to fully transparent by setting nil if it isn't animatable? - As is does in fact animate, just a second or two after the flicker

Comment: Not sure. It may also just be that uieffectviews are a pain in the neck when it comes to animation due to the way they grab the underlying view data and manipulate it.

Comment: @Paulw11 perhaps I could do `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and drop the delay parameter?

Comment: I would prefer to,wrap it in a `dispatch_after` and drop,the delay, but yes, that is what I was thinking you could try

Comment: @Paulw11 I see. Created the `dispatch_after` now, see update. Do I just put the whole animation block inside the dispatch?

Comment: Yes, you would put your `animateWithDuration` call in there

Comment: @Paulw11 that seems to do the trick! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the UIView animation methods actually execute the block immediately in order to determine the animatable properties that are being changed, and therefore your visual effect view is being set to nil immediately, since that is not an animatable property.

Rather than using `animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:...` you can use a simple `animateWithDuration` and use `dispatch_after` to delay the animation.

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.9;
dispatch_time_t reverseTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(reverseTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.5 initialSpringVelocity:2.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil;
        self.messageLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (handler) { handler(finished); }
    }];
});
```